# Turning off Eclipse 2020-06 Javascript Validation Notes

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation

Using Eclipse's 2020-06 built in JavaScript editor, I need to disable the JavaScript informational notes on syntax and warnings as displayed with an (i) icon to the left of the line number and with markers to the right of the scroll bar.  See links to the two images showing what these look like.

[image: The hover warning being shown]
[An example of the informational icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVHve.png)

[image: The numerous warning indicators shown to the right of the scrollbar]
[An example of the markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyf4v.png)

There are two warnings repeating numerous times:

- 'aVariableName' is declared but its value is never read.
- This constructor function may be converted to a class declaration.

I would rather turn off these two individual messages since they do not apply to the project, but such control does not appear to exist, but they are overly spamming the editor and are interfering with other notifications and informational notes.  FYI: I'm needing to follow specific coding conventions for the project and therefore the warnings don't even apply to the project and are just spam.

So I'll just settle for shutting off javascript validation, but the validation will not turn off.

I've tried to disable the project level settings for the javascript validation through the menu option Window, Preferences, Web, HTML Files, Client-side Javascript, Validator, Errors/Warnings: and unchecked both options of Strict Validation of Javascript keywords usage, and Enable JavaScript semantic validation.  But making those changes accomplishes nothing since the warnings are still there even after running validation on the project, cleaning the project, and even restarting eclipse.

The specific version of Eclipse is:
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers Version 2020-06 (4.16.0)

To try to better explain the need to install Node.js, this is the dialog requested Node.js be installed.  The text of the dialog reads: "Missing node.js" "Could not find node.js. This will result in editors missing key features. Please make sure node.js is installed and that your PATH environment variable contains the location to the 'node' executable."
[Eclipse's Missing Node.js dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYLMl.png)

Are there any other ways to shut off individual warnings/messages, or the javascript validations?  Any help, or constructive suggestions would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Sorry, the stackoverflow editor won't allow in-lining simple images.

Update: So I have not been able to figure out how to disable the informational notices that are showing up in the JavaScript editor along both the left and right margins.  I would still love to find out how to do that.  I'm wondering if the issues I'm seeing may have been resolved in the current release of Eclipse?  I cannot put my development environments at risk if downgrading is not possible. But some hopeful and important details that I have learned is that the latest release of Eclipse "can" support java 1.8 although it says the minimal version supported is Java 11.  And also the latest release is better integrated with Node.js so an external install is no longer required.  At this time I cannot risk testing the latest Eclipse release due to possible lockout of the workspaces if eclipse cannot be downgraded.  I will make plans to rebuild some of the workspaces on another workstation so it will not impact vital projects if something should go wrong.

Comment: Why are you using an outdated Eclipse? Which of the two JavaScript editors do you use and what do you have installed, Eclipse WTP JSDT or/and Eclipse Wild Web Developer? You didn't say which IDE package you have and cropped the screenshots, but from the error message I conclude the error is probably reported by the JavaScript language server (in the preferences _Language Servers_).

Comment: The use of 2020-06 is not what I would consider outdated, for it is the last edition of Eclipse that supports Java 1.8 which is needed for supporting many legacy infrastructures that cannot be migrated to java 11 at this time.  And some of which probably never can be migrated due to dependencies upon third party environments.

Comment: The specific version of Eclipse that I'm using is:
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers Version 2020-06 (4.16.0)
As far as the JavaScript editor that it's using internally, I'm not really sure how to identify that.  It forced me to install the 3.3 GB of Node.js to enable the JavaScript editor.  Crazy... 3.3 GB for an editor?! I guess they call that progress in some circles.  Sorry, but not sure if that gives any clues as to which editor it actually is.

Comment: The current Eclipse version 2021-03 supports Java 8 and even older Java versions. The current version of the Eclipse IDE package you have is shipped with an embedded Java 15 that is used to run Eclipse. For your projects you can use the embedded Java 15 or/and the Java installations of your system. Eclipse does not install 3.3 GB of Node.js. That might be a different tool or a plugin that you have installed.

Comment: I honestly have no idea about the dependencies upon Node.js.  Right after extracting a clean copy of 2020-06, without any addition of other plugins or tools, I tried to open a .js source member and it refused to open, siting that Node.js must be installed.  Without adding any plugins, I can only assume that it was a base requirement of the current Eclipse releases. Of course Eclipse does not install Node.js, but it did inform me that I must add it to access the javascript editor.  Nope... makes no sense to me either.

Comment: I updated the question above with a screen print of the dialog from Eclipse that is stating that Node.js is missing.  As you can see, that is why I stated that Eclipse required the installation of node.js.

Comment: You are currently wasting a lot of time doing retrocomputing. Yes, in the past that dialog ask you to install Node.js since it is required for the JavaScript/TypeScript and other language servers to run to provide support for JavaScript and other things (Eclipse Wild Web Developer embeds some language servers from VS Code written in TypeScript). Recent Wild Web Developer versions are shipped with an embedded Node.js requiring less than 150 MB inside your Eclipse installation directory and workspace; Node.js needs not to be installed on your system for that anymore.

Comment: I really appreciate the information you have been providing.  I was not aware of those details.  It's always been such a pain to upgrade eclipse in the past, that I've learned to avoid doing things that have resulted in extended down time.  Not sure if I can say I'm wasting a lot of time doing "retrocomputing" since it's part of the job description to maintain these old projects, but they are not funded to be upgraded.  Stuck in a catch-22 situation I guess. :(  Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to disable these javascript validation notes by changing the following setting.
Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors ->Text Editors -> Annotations

1. find "Infos" in the "Annotation types" and click it
2. uncheck both the "Vertical Ruler" and "Overview Ruler"
3. optional - uncheck "Text as "Squiggly Line"
4. Click Apply and Close
5. Voila enjoy the less cluttered javascript files

Comment: Thanks for the information.  That disables that kind of a notification, which may be useful in other circumstances.  But it's still good to know.  Thanks!